# Downvote bot or random downvoting?

Tags: support, down-votes, robots

I posted this question a few minutes ago:

- [Functional difference between normal method, Task, Paraller.invoke, async await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627976/functional-difference-between-normal-method-task-paraller-invoke-async-await)

And literally a second after I published it, I got an uncommented downvote.

I don't know if it's a bot or someone who loves me or the close question request which automatically downvotes, but I just thought about reporting it just in case you want to check and sort this out in case it's a bot.

I see the close request is for "too broad" but the questions are very precise, so I don't know.

Comment: @LiquidCore: Even myself, someone whose knowledge of C# is pretty minimal, can tell from the title alone that the question is too broad. That's why it was downvoted so quickly. Also the fact that you previously asked a similar question which was closed for the same reason.

Comment: @LiquidCore: As for why the downvote was cast, it's probably because your question represents a huge asymmetry of effort. From your question, I cannot tell that you understand what most of these things even are on a basic level. Again, as someone whose C# knowledge is minimal, I know enough to know that, if you have even a middling understanding of what `async` is/does, then by definition you know how they're different from non-`async` functions. So any answerers basically have to explain how all of these things work from first-principles. They spent more effort to answer than you did to ask.

Answer (score 6):

There's generally no bot running on Stack Overflow that downvotes questions based on certain criterion.

In this case, it appears there's a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627976/functional-difference-between-normal-method-task-paraller-invoke-async-await#comment99828173_56627976) on your original question that potentially explains the downvote.

Also, voting to close a question doesn't automatically downvotes it. Downvoting is done by system when the post is flagged (generally as spam).

Comment: Yeah, what puzzled me is how fast it was, literally 1 second after I posted it. Thanks